# Missing file error with Visual Studio and ReactJS; how can I know what file is requiring it?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

Sometimes, when I delete some .js files, I might forget to remove the import from other files. When I try to save it I get an error like this:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/lesson_manager/TextPage.js
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Xenomorph\Desktop\ez-class\front_end\src\lesson_manager\TextPage.js'
```

Now, I know I can use the search function to find what file has to be corrected, but is there a better way to figure out what file is requesting the missing file? Why the compiler is not telling me what file is looking for the missing file?

Comment: Hmm AFAIK there's no way to do this on compile time, but you can prevent this before it compiles, you can use eslint's eslint-plugin-import. Basically it will tell you right away if you have misspelled import, not existing import etc.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will try it out.